# While trying to compile a spigot plugin using maven, I run into an issue and am really tired of it

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

The Error: `net.atlas.SkyblockSandbox.player.SBPlayer is not abstract and does not override abstract method getTexture() in org.bukkit.entity.Player`

Some code I think is causing the issue

(If more is needed to help fix the issue please let me know!)

```
import com.xxmicloxx.NoteBlockAPI.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import net.atlas.SkyblockSandbox.*;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bukkit.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import static net.atlas.SkyblockSandbox.SBX.*;
import static net.atlas.SkyblockSandbox.*;

@Setter
public class SBPlayer extends PluginPlayer {

    static SBPlayer sbPlayer;
    public static HashMap<UUID, EntityDamageEvent.DamageCause> causes = new HashMap<>();

    public SBPlayer(Player player) {
        super(player);
        sbPlayer = this;
    }
```

Comment: you need to implement method getTexture() in SBPlayer

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying! I can't figure out exactly how to implement it? Do you think you could help me with that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should _never_ be extending `Player` or `PluginPlayer` in any form within a spigot/bukkit plugin, which is the cause of your error. These objects are created within the server itself, not for you to create.